# Can we Access Oracle NetSuite old cloud version?

Tags: java, oracle, netsuite, erp, suitecloud

We are having connector which will connect NetSuite ERP system using SOAP web services.

As we know NetSuite is Cloud based ERP system so to access this we login using NetSuite URL : https://system.netsuite.com/pages/customerlogin.jsp

Now I assume that, this is Cloud based system and they update there system 
for all its user

Example: 2019.1 for all NetSuite customers

Now some of our customers are saying there NetSuite version 2018.1 or 2015.1

Is it possible ? as this is cloud based system

I have gone through NetSuite help community but didn't find  any answers there

Comment: It is a commercial product, isn't it? So, when you pay money for using it, can't you just ask their support and expect an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SOAP API is called SuiteTalk and is versioned with numbers that match NetSuite releases. Older versions are supported for a long time even on newer NetSuite releases. Newer releases add new fields, record types among other things.

So an older integration or connector might use SuiteTalk 2016.2 to interact with a NetSuite 2019.1 instance. Each release uses a different endpoint (the release number is part of the URL when making the SOAP call).

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am aware about WSDL versions that we can connect 2016.end point to 2019.1 UI

But is it possible that any customer is using old NetSuite Version UI,  example : 2018.1 

. Our Customer has replied that there Oracle NetSuite Version is 2018.1 so I am confuse that is it possible as NetSuite is cloud based software

Comment: @SurajKudale The upgrades to a new release tend to be staggered across accounts. As well higher service levels do provide for selectable upgrade periods. Would be odd for them to be several releases behind however. Sandbox and developer accounts can also be behind sometimes.